# Change Page title when Pagingation the posts

Tags: plugin-development, pagination

I just changed the title tag in the header.php like this

```
<title><?php if ( $paged < 2 ) { } else { echo (' Page '); echo ($paged);} ?></title>
```

**Just want to change the title like** "Some Text - 2/7 - Some other Text"

where 2/7 refer to total pages of 7 and current visiting page is 2

How to change the title properly

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand this, you're trying to filter [`wp_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/) to include your pagination data.

You can change the format in the [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) first parameter and other params as per your needs. Please use with caution.

```
add_filter('wp_title', function( $title ) { 

    global $paged // page number
         , $wp_query; // WordPress query data

    if( ! is_feed() && (int) $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) {

        $title = sprintf(
            "%s - %d/%d - %s", // format
            get_bloginfo('name'), // blog name
            (int) $paged > 0 ? $paged : 1, // current page (goes 0 if no param set)
            $wp_query->max_num_pages, // max number of pages found
            get_bloginfo('description') // blog description
        );

    }

    return $title;

}, 999);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Newer themes will most likely not use the `wp_title()` function.

Comment: where do you write this function , what file to modify ?

Comment: Good morning. In your child theme's functions file ;)

Comment: Good morning to all, I'm little new to wordpress development , theme's functions file ->functions.php ? and how to call it properly in the header.php ?

Comment: I suggest to [create](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial) a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). Add the snippet of code in the answer to your created child `functions.php` file, that's all.